# Add a line below the navigationBar title

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

How can I add a second line (smaller font) below the navigationBar title as shown below? I want to show it below Sunday

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100404-8kaabe5f6b5bdf66wt9kfymepw.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100404-8kaabe5f6b5bdf66wt9kfymepw.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UINavigationItem prompt]` is what you're looking for.

You might set this in a `UIViewController`'s `initWithNibName:bundle:` (or `init` if you're not using XIBs) like this:

```
[[self navigationItem] setPrompt:@"The best day of the week"];
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, but this displays on top of my title, not below it. Do you know how could I put it below?

Comment: You can create a view that has two UILabels inside it, then set [UINavigationItem titleView] to this view. You'll have to make one label look like the default title, and the other one with smaller font to mimic the label appearance.